# git merge conflicts due to reverting: what strategies can be used to avoid such conflicts?

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

[image]

this images describes the issue we were facing

branch k had merged b2 into itself, which was a mistake, we actually did not want any b2 related changes going into k.

then k merged itself into b1, which brought in the b2 changes as well, which we do not want in b1

then k realized the mistake and does a revert commit and then merge itself into b1 again

then when we try to merge b1 to b2, we will face lots of conflicts due to the revert commit

In this case, what is the best way to avoid these conflicts?

What we did was recreated b1 and redid k's changes onto it, just wondering are there better ways to avoid such conflicts?

Comment: which workflow did the team follow? Git flow, trunk-based?

Comment: it was ad-hoc, unorganized way, which was why this mistake was not spotted earlier

Comment: IMO, without using the workflow, if you don't want to resolve merge conflicts and don't want B1 changes, squash merging the PRs and cherry picking might also help you save the time.